# regex match space forward slash and space ' / '

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Here is my string 'something / something else'
I would like to match with regex everything up to `/` i.e space forward slash space again. Here is what I tried =`/.+?(?=\s//\s)/`, but it does not work. It says: 'pattern contains no capture groups'. I am using it with pandas extract function.

Comment: `(?=` is a look-ahead assertion. it's not a capture group.

Comment: @MarcB. Thank you, but how can I fix it, I am noob in regex.

Comment: how about `/^(.*?) \//`? everything from start-of-string up to a space+slash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your requirements exactly, but this should do the trick:

```
(.*?)(?= \/ )
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/JJYyg0/1)

You can replace the `*` with a `+` if there must be at least one character before `/`.

The problem with your code is that [`pd.Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) expects a "regular expression pattern **with capturing groups**." Your regex includes a positive lookahead (`?=`) but does not have a captured group (something between parentheses). If you surround `.+?` with parentheses in your example, it should work, but note that `\s` captures *any* whitespace, not just spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
r'^([^/]+) / '
```

- `^([^/]+)` matches everything upto the `/`, then `/` matches a space, then `/`, and then a space again. SO the captured group 1 will only have the portion upto the space before `/`

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'something / something else'
>>> re.search(r'^([^/]+) / ', s).group(1)
'something'
```

Comment: The primary issue is the pandas library, which requires a capturing group for the function. Also, I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't want the ` / ` to be part of the captured group.

Comment: @brianpck Edited.